# grabbing an image from a facebook url without cURL

Tags: php, parsing, curl

I have a url of a Facebook page. 
I want to be able to grab the image from the url, however the server that I am using is operating in cURL safe mode. I am trying to save the image to my server. I have made some attempts at it, however, all of the attempts I have made have resulted in an error due to my servers limited capabilities. Is this even possible without cURL?

Example of what I have so far:

```
<?

function getImages($url) {

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(CURLOPT_URL => $url, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true));

  $results = curl_exec($ch);

  $doc = new DOMDocument();

  $doc->loadHTML($results);

  $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

  return($images);
}

getImages('http://t.co/vPnWwPy8');

?>
```

EDIT: The error I receive is:

> Warning: curl_setopt_array() [function.curl-setopt-array]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use file_get_contents().

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php